# sql with clause in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have this SQL query:

```
WITH excluded_authors as 
    (SELECT author_id from authors_books)
SELECT authors.* from authors 
     WHERE authors.id not in 
     (SELECT author_id FROM excluded_authors)
```

The objective here is to get all the authors that have no books yet.

How do I formulate that query in rails (other than copying it into `find_by_sql` ?

**EDIT**

I tried this:

```
Author.where.not("\"authors\".\"id\" in \"authors_bilios\".\"authors_id\"")
```

Comment: I tried `find_by_sql`  which works and and the `where.not` which doesn't work. `find_by_sql` is maybe not the most satisfactory way of doing that. Is this why you downvoted the question?

Comment: At stackoverflow it's expected that you show what you've already tried, and then ask for help. You'll get much better help that way.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I edited my question to show what I have done. I have something working, but simply wondering whether there's a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simplest way probably, it doesn't scale very well though, so be aware of that if you have thousands or millions of rows.

```
author_ids = AuthorsBooks.pluck(:author_id)
@authors = Author.where('id not in (?)', author_ids)
```

Edit: 
You can avoid the double query with

```
@authors = Author.where('id not in (select author_id from authors_books)')
# and using `not`
@authors = Author.where.not(id: AuthorBook.select(:author_id))
```

Comment: You can use pure ActiveRecord syntax: `Author.where.not(id: AuthorBook.select(:author_id))`

Comment: @BrunoBispo Yes indeed